# I am making a CPS counter but am having trouble with the timer?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to tkinker in python (Really new) and am having some trouble making and displaying a timer for a CPS calculator (Like this one: http://www.mcrpg.com/kohi-click-test).

I have tried a couple of solutions but none have seemed to work.
Example one:

```
while True:
    if seconds > -10:
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds += 1
        secs.configure(text=seconds)
```

In this example it makes the `window.mainloop()` unreachable.
When it doesn't have the `while True:` and `window.mainloop()` is reachable it only updates 'seconds' once. (0 --> 1)

It says not to include my entire code, hopefully I have only included the necessary code.

Timer code:

```
# Seconds

secs = Label(window, text=0, fg='white', bg='blue')
secs.grid(column=6, row=6)


if seconds > -10:
    time.sleep(1)
    seconds += 1
    secs.configure(text=seconds)

window.mainloop()
```

My variables:

```
from tkinter import *
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import time

window = Tk()

clicks = 0

window.title("CPS TEST")

window.geometry('500x500')

lbl = Label(window, text='CPS TEST', bg='orange')

lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

clicks1 = 0

seconds = 0
```

I expect the `secs` in the window to be updated every second, adding one to the variable, making the number go up. Is there anyway I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is an *event-driven* system, like most GUI toolkits. For it to function properly, your code is basically a guest in the `mainloop()` and must be called from it.
So your code must live in *callbacks*. You could say that there are two kinds of callbacks;

- callbacks attached to widgets (e.g. for when a button is pressed)
- callbacks invoked by a timer (using `Tk.after`)

Using the firstkind of callback, you can record the `datetime.datetime` every time the callback is invoked. Append that `datetime` to a `global` list.

Using the second kind of callback (e.g called every second), you could calculate the difference between subsequent items in the list of `datetime`.  That will give you `timedelta` objects.  Then set the list to a empty list.  Average the timedeltas and invert it if the average is not 0.  That gives you CPS.  Use that to update the display.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Roland Smith's answer, to continue the `root.after()` multiple times you can make it recursive. So it would look something like this

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text='Time: ')
label.pack()

time = Label(root, text=0)
time.pack()

def update_time():
    time.configure(text=time.cget('text') + 1)
    root.after(1000, update_time)

root.after(1000, update_time)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is old and my code does not use tkinter, but I just wanted to share it anyway

```py
from pynput.mouse import Listener
from time import sleep, time
from threading import Thread
import os.path
from pyfiglet import Figlet

f = Figlet ( font = "roman" )
print ( "\x1b[?25l" )
clicks = [ ]

def reduce ( ) :
  while True :
    removed = [ i for i in clicks if time ( ) - i > 1 ]
    for i in removed : clicks.remove ( i )
    #print ( "\x1b[1;1H\x1b[J" )
    print ( f.renderText ( str ( len ( clicks ))))
    if os.path.isfile ( "stop" ) :
      print ( "\x1b[?25h" )
      return

def on_click ( x, y, button, pressed ):
  if pressed and str ( button ) == "Button.left" :
    global clicks
    clicks += [ time ( )]

x = Thread ( target = reduce )
x.start ( )

with Listener ( on_click = on_click ) as listener:
  listener.join ( )
```

It also creates a neat console window with a big number telling you the CPS